# Properties in custom UITableViewCell are not getting initialized for a UISearchDisplayController's table

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using a UISearchDisplayController to be able to display a table with custom cells based on some data I am retrieving from a server.

First I set the UISearchDisplayController inside my UIViewController.

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                             initWithSearchBar:self.mySearchBar contentsController:self];
        self.searchController.delegate = self;
        self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
        self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

My UIViewController also implements the UISearchBarDelegate, so I can determine when a search starts. I set up a block so when my api call returns it gets called and a dictionary of results is saved in the self.searchResults property:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // here we make the api call
    [api getSomeInfo:searchBar.text complete:^(NSDictionary *json) {

        self.searchResults = json;
        [self.searchController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Now, the problem I have is that in my UITableViewDataSource method, where I return the custom cell. My cell is instantiated, but it's IBOutlets never get initialized, so I cannot set their content (text, images, etc) properly:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (tableView == self.searchController.searchResultsTableView) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultsCellIndentifier"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[SearchResultsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.customLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectForKey:@"customText"];  // cell exists but cell.customLabel is nil!!
    }

}
```

Why is the content nil? Is there somewhere in my Custom Cell class where I should be setting the content up?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to point out that I used Interface Builder to create the custom cell. It is under the UIViewController's Prototype Cells and it has it's identifier @"SearchResultsCellIndentifier"

Comment: Found the answer here: http://bit.ly/y4XXen

The problem is when you try to dequeue a Reusable cell and get nothing back. I then tried to create a new cell.

I actually had to dequeue the reusable cell from the UIViewController's tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you used the variable `cellIdentifier` when creating the cell, but a string constant when dequeuing.

Simply always recreating a cell will work, but is not efficient at all and leads to major memory leaks.

You should first set the cellIdentifier according to which table view you are in, and which kind of cell you need, then dequeue with that cellIdentifier, and then create a new one if needed.